# Combine two functions in Python without extra overhead of explicitly calling functions

Tags: python, function, performance, python-decorators, overhead

Is there a way to combine two functions in python without the cost of calling two extra functions? For example, running:

```
from time import time

func1 = lambda x, y: x * y
func2 = lambda x, y: x + y

combinedFunc1 = lambda x, y: func1(x, y) * func2(x, y)
combinedFunc2 = lambda x, y: (x * y) * (x + y)

start = time()
for x, y in zip(range(10_000_000), range(10_000_000)):
    temp = combinedFunc1(x, y)

print(f'Combined Function #1: {time() - start}')

start = time()
for x, y in zip(range(10_000_000), range(10_000_000)):
    temp = combinedFunc2(x, y)

print(f'Combined Function #2: {time() - start}')
```

Results in:

```
'Combined Function #1: 3.116791248321533'
'Combined Function #2: 2.068246364593506'
```

`combinedFunc1` is 50% slower due to the extra function calls (I'm assuming this is the reason). Is there a way to combine `func1` and `func2` in a way such as `combinedFunc2` so as not to deal with the extra overhead of calling two more functions, **for an unknown `func` and `func2`** (i.e. without knowing what `func1` and `func2` are calculating?)

Ideally I would like to combine an indeterminate number of functions, but I expect that knowing how to do so with two functions results in a way to do so with arbitrarily many.